# What does it mean by saying conflating environment and object is the fundamental sin of Javascript?

Tags: javascript, programming-languages

I was watching programming languages courses given by Prof. Shriram Krishnamurthi  on youtube.

In this episode,
https://youtu.be/SUh7jhrtktk?t=1600

He said conflating environment and objects is the fundamental sin of Javascript. The environment is exposed to language users, and the users can manipulate the environment.

I don't quite understand what he means actually. Does he refer to how "this" works in Javascript?

Are there any code examples which can demonstrate this sin?

Answer (score 1):

After a little bit of digging, I’ve found a paper from Professor Shriram’s group.

https://cs.brown.edu/research/plt/dl/jssem/v1/

In section 2.5, they pointed out that it is not clear whether JavaScript is lexically scoped because the scope chain in javascript is formed with ordinary objects, and *with* statement lets programmers add arbitrary objects to the scope chain.

I think I now fully understand what he means in the video.

I highly recommend this paper. It indeed catches all of the essence of javascript according to its title, not only the good part, but also the bad part.